# https stops working after site publish

Tags: ssl, iis-6, https

I am working on Windows Server 2003 (IIS6), which has two asp.net sites running in seperate app pools. One of the sites has an ssl certificate installed and was running fine on https. The other site has no certificate and does not require https

The problem I have is that when I publish my app from vs2005 to the site with ssl the https urls stop working and I can only use http. The error I get is as follows

From Google Chrome: Error 104 (net::ERR_CONNECTION_FAILED): The attempt to connect to the server failed.

From IE7: Internet explorer cannot display the web page, could be unavailable, dns is not reachable etc

The strange thing is the first time this happened, https eventually became available but I don't know what triggered the availability but when I published an updated assembly to the bin folder of the site which does not require https, the OTHER site became unavailable on https again

Help much appreciated!

UPDATED: Thanks for the suggestions but it turns out that the firewall was not open on the ssl port

Comment: Are both webs on the same IP address?

Comment: The secure site is on a specified IP and the non-secure site is on (All Unassigned)

The secure site uses 443 and the non-secure site has the ssl port empty

When testing on another machine the error returned was 504 proxy timeout, but again the exact same site on http runs fine

Comment: What happens if you open https:// IP_ADDRESS / - the secure site should load.

Comment: trying to imagine what could trigger this: are the two sites in two "physical" subfolders (relative to each other)?

Comment: https://IP_ADDRESS/ attempts to load the secure site but fails. http://IP_ADDRESS/ does not resolve. The sites are in relative "physical" subfolders e.g. websites/site1 & websites/site2

Comment: Is there a "shared" web.config in the parent folder (websites)?

Comment: Not a shared web.config.

Comment: Both sites share the same domain, secure site has a different subdomain, secure.domain.com. When things are okay with the secure site, when I try https://www.domain.com I get a warning as expected that the certificate does not match the domain. But when it stops working, no warning, just times out

Comment: I've just tried https://IP_ADDRESS/ from the server itself, which loads ok but warns that the certificate was not registered for the address. Tried https://IP_ADDRESS/ external to the server which does not load

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check if the firewall port for SSL (443) wasn't accidentally closed 443. ;-)

Answer (score 1):

If both webs use the same IP address, make sure, that **only the web with the certificate uses the SSL port 443** (first property page). The input field should be empty for the insecure site.

If that is not the problem, you could try to debug stopping the web without certificate and restart the web server.